# How to disable gnome-xchat join/quit massage permanently?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, ubuntu-12.04

I use the gnome-xchat comes with ubuntu 12.04.

Is there a way to disable join/quit-massage for all channels permanently?

Answer (score 2):

In `.xchat2/xchat.conf`, set:

```
 irc_conf_mode = 1
```

Which enables the conference mode.  In other words, it hides who joins/parts/quits a channel.